# Please explain perl statement

Tags: perl, sorting

I am reading Intermediate Perl book and in Chapt10 there is this code. I added few print statements but core logic is untouched.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @input = qw(Gilligan Skipper Professor Ginger Mary Ann);
my @sorted_positions = sort { $input[$a] cmp $input[$b] } 0 .. $#input;
print Dumper( \@sorted_positions );
my @ranks;
@ranks[@sorted_positions] = ( 1 .. @sorted_positions );
print Dumper( \@ranks );
foreach ( 0 .. $#ranks ) {
    print "$input[$_] sorts into position $ranks[$_]\n";
}
```

When i check the Dumper output then for `@sorted_positions` array it is printing

```
$VAR1 = [
          5,
          0,
          3,
          4,
          2,
          1
        ];
```

which make sense to me but for `@ranks` array it is printing

```
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          6,
          5,
          3,
          4,
          1
        ];
```

I am unable to understand what this line is doing.

```
@ranks[@sorted_positions] = ( 1 .. @sorted_positions );
```

I am able understand what output means in reference to the program but not able to understand how that output is coming i.e. what exactly is perl doing inside that statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line:

```
@ranks[@sorted_positions] = ( 1 .. @sorted_positions );
```

is equivalent to:

```
@ranks[5,0,3,4,2,1] = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$ranks[5] = 1;
$ranks[0] = 2;
$ranks[3] = 3;
$ranks[4] = 4;
$ranks[2] = 5;
$ranks[1] = 6;
```

The example is using `slices` which are documented in the [`perldata` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Answer (score 3):

Let suppose you want to assign string 'x' into the first position of an array, 'y' into the second position and 'z' into the third position.  Instead of doing three assignments, you can do them at the same time;

```
@array[0,1,2] = ("x", "y", "z");
```

You don't have to do these in order;

```
@array[2,0,1] = ("z", "x", "y");    # same result
```

The **right-hand side** of the line in question produces a list of numbers starting with 1 and finishing at the integer value returned by the expression `@sorted_positions` (which is 6 as there are 6 things in @sorted_positions) - ie its *identical* to;

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

So, **the whole statement** is identical to:

```
@ranks[5,0,3,4,2] = (1,2,3,4,5,6) ;
```

So, if we take just one iteration of this:

```
foreach ( 0 .. $#ranks ) {
    print "$input[$_] sorts into position $ranks[$_]\n";
}
```

we get;

```
print "$input[0] sorts into position $ranks[0]\n" 
# ie: Gilligan sorts into position 2
```

Hope that helps.